# Compute $\iint_D e^{-(2x^2-2xy+5y^2)}\arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{x-2y}\right)dA$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Compute$$\iint_D e^{-(2x^2-2xy+5y^2)}\arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{x-2y}\right)dA$$

over the region $D$, defined by $1\leq 2x^2 -2xy +5y^2\leq 9, (1-\sqrt3)x+(1+2\sqrt3)y\geq 0$ and $\sqrt3(x+y) \geq x-2y$.

**My try:**

I noted that $2x^2-2xy+5y^2 = (x-2y)^2 + (x+y)^2$. So I let $u=x+y, v=x-2y$, then, I can rewrite the domain $D$: $1 \leq u^2 + v^2 \leq 9, \frac{u}{v} \geq \sqrt{3}, \frac{u}{v} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ (if $x-2y > 0$). After that, I also rewrite the integrand as follows (omitting the computation of the Jacobian Determinant):

$$\frac{1}{3}\iint_D e^{-(u^2+v^2)}\arctan\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)dA$$

Now, it is clear that I need to use polar coordinates: $u=r\sin(\theta), v=r\cos(\theta)$. Now, I can rewrite the integrand again:

$$\frac{1}{3} \iint e^{-r^2}r\theta \, dr \,d\theta$$

But in the end, I have problems computing the domain (the limits of integration). I know that $1 \leq r \leq 3$, but for the angle I have doubts, I don't know how to prooced. Any hints or corrections in my procedure are appreciated.

Comment: Keep the inequalities on $u, v$ in the form $1 < u^2 + v^2 < 9 \land u > v \sqrt 3 \land u \sqrt 3 > v$. Draw the resulting region in the $vu$-plane to determine the angles ($\theta$ is the angle between the vector $(v, u)$ and the $v$-axis). Note that the integrand is discontinuous, $\arctan \tan \theta \neq \theta$. If you choose $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$, you should get
$$\frac 1 3 \int_{\theta_1}^{\pi/2} \int_1^3
 e^{-r^2} \theta r \, dr d\theta +
\frac 1 3 \int_{\pi/2}^{\theta_2} \int_1^3
 e^{-r^2} (\theta - \pi) r \, dr d\theta.$$

Comment: I computed $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ and I obtained $\theta_1 = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\theta_2 = \frac{7\pi}{6}$. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Manipulating arctangents of expressions of the form $\dfrac{ax+by}{cx+dy}$ is a thing. And I am aware of that but not skilled in that. It starts with $\arctan x + \arctan y = \arctan\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}.$ And it is widely known that expressions like $2x^2 -2xy + 5y^2$ can be written as $u^2+v^2$ for $u = \square x+\square y$ and $v=\square x + \square y$ with suitable numbers in the roles of the four $\text{“}\square\text{''s}.$ So I wonder it one can somehow reduce this to
$$
\int e^{-u^2} \arctan u\, du.
$$